# returning multiple items from a PHP iterator

Tags: php, iterator

Is there a way with a PHP Iterator object to sometimes return multiple items from a single item?

For example, suppose I have an array:

`$a = ['1','2','3','double 6','4'];`

and I want to have an Iterator object that takes this and produces the following items:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 6
- 6
- 4

Comment: what other than `double`  ?

Comment: Is `double double 6` possible?

Comment: what is this? code golf?

Comment: This will probably have a good explanation, but why not return the array? Often in comparable situations, it turned out my code was brittle and returning the array was more than enough.

Comment: I don't see why is code golf. It's a silly example because my actual use case is complicated. I want to use an Iterator over an array, and for some items in the source I want the Iterator to return multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

One way that has occurred to me since posting the question is to use a Generator instead:

`function my_iteration($data) {
  foreach ($data as $item) {
    if (IS DOUBLE) {
      yield $item;
      yield $item;
    }
    else {
      yield $item;
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like flattening the array. If you are not worried about the memory you can use an initial array in the following form:

```
$array = ['1', '2', '3', ['6', '6'], '4'];
```

And then use [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php):

```
function flatArray1($array): iterator
{
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
    foreach ($iterator as $item) {
        yield $item;   
    }
}

print_r(iterator_to_array(flatArray1($array)));
```

If you want to use less memory you can use a kind of zipped version of an initial array:

```
$array = ['1', '2', '3', [2, '6'], '4'];

function flatArray2($array): iterator
{
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            [$count, $item] = $item;

            while ($count) {
                yield $item;

                $count -= 1;
            }

            continue;
        }

        yield $item;
    }
}

print_r(iterator_to_array(flatArray2($array)));
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55250d7250d265f6cdf88c07d77eeeff0a5813da).

Answer (score -1):

You have to make of definite array for such string like

`"double"=>2,"triple"=>3,"quadruple"=>4, "quintuple"=>5`

```
<?php
  $str = ["double"=>2,"triple"=>3,"quadruple"=>4, "quintuple"=>5];
  $a = ['1','2','3','double 6','4'];
  foreach($a as $key=>$val){
    $val = explode(" ",$val);
    if(count($val) > 1){
      $a[$key] = $val[1];
      for($i=1;$i<$str[$val[0]];$i++){
        $a[] = $val[1];
      }
    }
  }
  sort($a);
  print_r($a);
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1000871)

Comment: I specifically want to use an Iterator class, not foreach. Sorry, should have been clearer in the question.

Comment: Share some more examples

Comment: My actual use case has a lot of detail that would just add noise here. It really just boils down to: sometimes, an item in the data being iterated should yield more than one item.

Comment: @joachim: do you still want answer or want to delete your question?